# How to open 'Go to definition' in other split tab for same file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm considerably new to Visual Studio Code and I am struggling a bit with an easy functionality. Imagine the case when I am reviewing some code in a file a.py and I select 'Go to definition' on a function x of the same file. Is there any possible configuration or shortcut that opens the definition on a split on the editor?

I have tried having already the same file split in the editor an it still opens the definition in the same file what is uncomfortable when you have to trace some code because you need to scroll up and down whenever you want to see another function of the same file.

An extension that allows to do the trick will also be well received. Thanks.

Comment: Using Visual Studio, I usually just open a new window on the file, move to the line in question in the new window, and then do the Go to definition. That way I have two windows open on the same file viewing different parts of the file.

Comment: @RichardChambers Yeah, that is more or less what I do, but it is slow and tedious and I would like some kind of automation on that action so code reviews could be made easily. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: As an alternative to the navigation problem, I've found a shortcut that gets you to the place where your cursor was placed previously. At least it eases navigation pain. It is `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `-`.

Comment: There's 2 recent VS Code feature requests that would add the option to use the left most split when on the right most split instead of opening more splits to the right:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190836
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190643

If people upvote these feature requests, we might get it added to VS Code.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve this.

Either:

1. Left-click function name that you want to open.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>t</kbd>
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>enter</kbd>

Or:

1. Change setting `Editor > Goto Location: Multiple` to be `gotoAndPeek` or `goto`
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + [click on function name]

Both methods will open the definition in the split to the right (or create a new split if this is the right-most split).

You like?

Comment: The second one with `gotoAndPeek` works like a charm and is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: What if we want to open the file in a split to the left?

Comment: @ForeverWintr Sorry I don't think that's possible. I think the idea is for us to always work primarily on the left-most split and drill-down further and further towards the right. I guess we need to adopt this approach.

Comment: @ForeverWintr Actually take a look at the settings `Workbench > Editor: Open Positioning` and `Workbench > Editor: Open Side By Side Direction` - these let you set the direction of the split!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the follow up!

Comment: "goto location: multiple" controls what happens when you have multiple definitions, I don't think that's what OP is asking.

Comment: There's 2 recent VS Code feature requests that would add the option to use the left most split when on the right most split instead of opening more splits to the right:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190836
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190643

If people upvote these feature requests, we might get it added to VS Code.

Answer (score 15):

For me setting `workbench.editor.revealIfOpen` to true like described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82767) worked.

> Controls whether an editor is revealed in any of the visible groups if opened. If disabled, an editor will prefer to open in the currently active editor group. If enabled, an already opened editor will be revealed instead of opened again in the currently active editor group. Note that there are some cases where this setting is ignored, e.g. when forcing an editor to open in a specific group or to the side of the currently active group.

Comment: This worked for me. For example, if I have file `x` on the left side and file `y` on the right.
If I want to see the definition by clicking a method on the left that's defined on the right, it won't open `y` file again on the left. Thanks!

Comment: Kinda wild that this would be disabled by default, but I'm glad this option exists.

Comment: There's 2 recent VS Code feature requests that would add the option to use the left most split when on the right most split instead of opening more splits to the right:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190836
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190643

If people upvote these feature requests, we might get it added to VS Code.

Answer (score 13):

- <kbd>option</kbd>  +  <kbd>command</kbd>  +  <kbd>left click</kbd>

or

- <kbd>option</kbd>  +  <kbd>command</kbd>  +  <kbd>F12</kbd>

opens the definition in the split tab.

Comment: interesting shortcut! It'd be good if it could just use the other side tab instead of keep creating a split tab

Comment: There's 2 recent VS Code feature requests that would add the option to use the left most split when on the right most split instead of opening more splits to the right:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190836
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190643

If people upvote these feature requests, we might get it added to VS Code.

Answer (score 10):

The shortcut is Ctrl+K, F12 but this can be changed in the shortcuts (search for shortcut editor.action.revealDefinitionAside)
More details here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112136

Comment: this has the same problem as "option + command + left click" where it will keep creating new tab on the side instead of reusing the other side tab

Comment: There's 2 recent VS Code feature requests that would add the option to use the left most split when on the right most split instead of opening more splits to the right:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190836
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190643

If people upvote these feature requests, we might get it added to VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different ways to do that task:
First one is, with the cursor on the word that you want to go to definition, press `Alt+F12`.
It opens a new tab like this one:

[image]

Second one is edit the settings and add this line:

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

It disables all the previews for code files so always that you want to go to definition, they will be open in a new tab, as you can see here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but these trick does not get the functionality I want. I want the code in two sides on a plit so I can see both at the same time. The first one does not do nothing, when pressing only `F12` I go to the definition in the classic way, when pressing `Shift+ALT+F12` it finds all references, but when I press `Alt+F12` it does nothing. taking into account the other option, I already have that setting disabled from settings, so I think it has nothing to do with it.